# Is there a way to use datepicker functions as events

Tags: jquery, datepicker

I have an application with multiple modules that need to integrate with a single datepicker instance.  So, for example, when onChangeMonthYear is called I want to trigger:

```
moduleA.onChangeMonthYear 
moduleB.onChangeMonthYear 
moduleC.onChangeMonthYear
```

It doesn't seems like the datepicker on[x] functions are designed to do this, but maybe I'm missing something.  In other words, I want to use the on[x] functions as events.

Has anybody found a solution for this scenario?  If so, can you provide some links or examples?

If the answer is no...  I'm experimenting with something I'm calling a DatepickerCallstack which registers anonymous callbacks and is executed from the datepicker on[x] setting.  It works for a few iterations, then something weird happens.  It almost looks like an internal reference issue.  So far it only happens with beforeShowDay.  I can see thru console debugging/inspections that the arguments passed into the callback are correct, but jQuery disagrees: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined

```
function DatepickerCallStack() {
    this.callstack = {
        onChangeMonthYear: {},
        beforeShow: {},
        beforeShowDay: {},
        onSelect: {},
        onClose: {}
    };
}

DatepickerCallStack.prototype = {
    constructor: DatepickerCallStack,
    register: function(event, callback, reference) {

        if (typeof event !== 'string' || event === '') {
            throw Error("Invalid event argument.");
        } else if (!this.callstack.hasOwnProperty(event)) {
            throw Error("Unsupported event: " + event);
        }

        if (typeof callback !== 'function') {
            throw Error("Invalid callback argument.");
        }

        if (reference) {
            if (reference !== 'string' || reference === '') {
                throw Error("Invalid reference argument.");
            }
        } else {
            reference = 'callback' + Object.size(this.callstack[event]).toString();
        }

        this.callstack[event][reference] = callback;

    },
    unregister: function(event, reference) {
        if (typeof event !== 'string' || event === '') {
            throw Error("Invalid event argument.");
        } else if (!this.callstack.hasOwnProperty(event)) {
            throw Error("Unsupported event: " + event);
        }

        if (reference !== 'string' || reference === '') {
            throw Error("Invalid reference argument.");
        } else if (!this.callstack[event].hasOwnProperty(reference)) {
            throw Error("Reference does not exists: " + reference);
        }

        delete this.callstack[event][reference];
    },
    execute: function(event, args) {
        if (Object.size(this.callstack[event]) === 0) {
            switch(event) {
                case 'beforeShowDay':
                    return [true, ''];
                case 'beforeShow':
                    return {};
                case 'onChangeMonthYear':
                case 'onSelect':
                case 'onClose':
                    return;
            }
        }

        var self = this,
            result;

        Object.keys(this.callstack[event]).forEach(function(reference) {
            var callback = self.callstack[event][reference];
            switch(event) {
                case 'beforeShowDay':
                    result = callback(args.date);
                    return (typeof result === 'object') ? result : [true, ''];
                case 'beforeShow':
                    result = callback(args.input, args.inst);
                    return (typeof result === 'object') ? result : {};
                case 'onChangeMonthYear':
                    callback(args.year, args.month, args.inst);
                    break;
                case 'onSelect':
                    callback(args.dateText, args.inst);
                    break;
                case 'onClose':
                    callback(args.dateText, args.inst);
                    break;
            }
        });
    }
};
```

This is how it is initialized...

```
window.DPCS = new DatepickerCallStack;

var dp_settings = {
        beforeShow: function(input, inst) {
            return window.DPCS.execute('beforeShow', {input:input, inst:inst});
        },
        beforeShowDay: function(date) { 
            return window.DPCS.execute('beforeShowDay', {date:date});
        },
        onChangeMonthYear: function(year, month, inst) {
            window.DPCS.execute('onChangeMonthYear', {year:year, month:month, inst:inst});
        },
        onSelect: function(dateText, inst) {
            window.DPCS.execute('onSelect', {dateText:dateText, inst:inst});
        },
        onClose: function(dateText, inst) {
            window.DPCS.execute('onClose', {dateText:dateText, inst:inst});
        },
        dateFormat:'mm-dd-yy'
    };

window.DPCS.register('onChangeMonthYear', customOnChangeMonthYear);
window.DPCS.register('beforeShowDay', customBeforeShowDay);
```

Thanks.

Comment: Why can't you add the events that need to be called in the on[x] handlers ?

Comment: Vignesh, can you elaborate?  I need to be able to add additional callbacks dynamically, because some scenarios do not apply to all modules/sub-workflows.  For example,
Scenario 1: onChangeMonthYear might call moduleA.onChangeMonthYear and  moduleC.onChangeMonthYear
Scenario 2: onChangeMonthYear might only call moduleB.onChangeMonthYear

Comment: You mean u need to call specific events related to the modules when some event is triggered in jQuery datepicker ?

Answer (score 0):

This might help you. You need to set the `events` to be called dynamically on different scenarios using the following.

```
$('#datepicker').datepicker( 'option' , 'onChangeMonthYear', function (date) {
    //code goes here
});
```

Example :

```js
$( "#datepicker" ).datepicker();

function A() { console.log("A"); }
function B() { console.log("B"); }

document.querySelector("#a").addEventListener("click",function(){
    $('#datepicker').datepicker( 'option' , 'onChangeMonthYear', function (date) {
        A();
    });
});

document.querySelector("#b").addEventListener("click",function(){
    $('#datepicker').datepicker( 'option' , 'onChangeMonthYear', function (date) {
        B();
    });
});

document.querySelector("#c").addEventListener("click",function(){
    $('#datepicker').datepicker( 'option' , 'onChangeMonthYear', function (date) {
        A();
        B();
    });
});
```

```html
<link href="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>


<input type="text" id="datepicker">
<br>
<button id="a">Set scenario A : Calls function A</button>
<button id="b">Set scenario B : Calls function B</button>
<button id="c">Set scenario C : Calls functions A & B</button>
```